Gradient Descent for SE(2) Transformation Matrix Estimation
% Initialisation
clear all;
%close all;

num_iterations = 50;
sigma = 0.01;
alpha = 0.00001; 
L = sigma^2*diag(ones(3,1));
% P = (L+L')/2;
N_values = 100;
Nr = 10;
E = [0, -1; 1, 0];
T_estim_history = zeros(3, 3, num_iterations);

% Fonction pour calculer l'opérateur vee
function a = vee_operator(wedge)
    a = wedge(2, 1);
end

% Génération d'une matrice de transformation aléatoire dans SE(2)
function T = rand_transformation_matrix()
    theta = 2 * pi * rand();
    R = [cos(theta), -sin(theta); sin(theta), cos(theta)];
    t = rand(2, 1);
    T = [R, t; 0, 0, 1];
end

% Fonction V(θ) pour SE(2)
function V = V_operator(theta)
    if abs(theta) < 1e-12
        V = eye(2);
    else
        V = (sin(theta) / theta) * eye(2) + ((1 - cos(theta)) / theta) * [0, -1; 1, 0];
    end
end

% Fonction exponentielle pour les matrices de transformation SE(2)
function exp_W = exp_operator_se2(tau)
    theta = tau(3);
    R = [cos(theta), -sin(theta); sin(theta), cos(theta)];
    rho = tau(1:2);
    t = V_operator(theta) * rho;
    exp_W = [R, t; 0, 0, 1];
end


% Fonction pour calculer la pseudo-inverse d'une matrice
function inv_A = robust_inv(A)
    [U, S, V] = svd(A);
    tol = max(size(A)) * eps(norm(S));
    S_inv = diag(1 ./ diag(S));
    S_inv(S < tol) = 0;  
    inv_A = V * S_inv * U';
end

% Fonction pour calculer le logarithme pour SE(2)
function log_tau = log_operator_se2(M)
    R = M(1:2, 1:2);
    t = M(1:2, 3);
    theta = vee_operator(logm(R));
    V_inv = robust_inv(V_operator(theta)); 
    rho = V_inv * t;
    log_tau = [rho; theta];
end


for n = 1:numel(N_values)
    N = N_values(n);
    mse_history = zeros(Nr, 1);

    for nr = 1:Nr
        errors_history = zeros(num_iterations, 1);

        T = rand_transformation_matrix();

        Z = zeros(3, 3, N);
        for i = 1:N
            a = sigma * randn(3, 1);
            Zi = T * exp_operator_se2(a);
            Z(:, :, i) = Zi;
        end

        T_est = T; 
        e = log_operator_se2(inv(T) * T_est);
        errors_history(1) = norm(e);
      
        for iter = 2:num_iterations
              grad = zeros(3,1);
            % Calcul de l'erreur et du gradient
            errors = [];
            J_l_sum = zeros(3); 
            for l = 1:size(Z, 3)
                Zi = Z(:, :, l);
                error = log_operator_se2(T_est^-1 * Zi);
                J_l = Jl(T_est(1:2, 1:2), T_est(1:2, 3), Zi, E);
              
                J_l_sum = J_l_sum + J_l;
                errors = [errors, error];
                grad = grad - 2 * inv(L) * error;

            end 
            
            % Mise à jour de T_est selon la descente de gradient sur le groupe de Lie
            delta_T = -alpha * grad;
            T_est = T_est * exp_operator_se2(delta_T);

            % Calcul de l'erreur
            e = log_operator_se2(inv(T) * T_est);
            errors_history(iter) = norm(e);
            T_estim_history(:, :, iter) = T_est;
        end
        
        mse_history(nr) = errors_history(end)^2;
    end
end

% Tracer l'évolution de l'erreur pour chaque itération
figure;
plot(1:num_iterations, errors_history);
xlabel('Iteration');
ylabel('Erreur');
title(['Evolution de l''erreur pour N = ', num2str(N)]);


My algorithm diverges. What can I do? I have tried modifying the number of iterations, the step size, and the learning rate (

α), but the issue persists. Here are some additional steps you can take to address the problem:
Check for Correct Gradient Calculation: Ensure that the gradient is computed correctly. Errors in the gradient calculation can lead to divergence.
Decrease the Learning Rate: Sometimes, a smaller learning rate (

α) can stabilize the algorithm. If

α is too large, the updates may overshoot the minimum, causing divergence.
Normalize the Data: Ensure that the input data is normalized. Large values can cause instability in the algorithm.
Initialize Parameters Carefully: Use a good initialization strategy for your transformation matrices. Poor initialization can lead to divergence.
